# Mobile Device Center Passthrough to use internet connection from Device

Tags: windows-ce

Searching for a way to access the internet on a Windows Mobile/CE device through desktop PC's connection while connected via Device Center.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my finding, if you add the following registry entry, then restart Device Center (stop process and start) or reboot PC, the device can access the internet.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services]
  "AllowLSP"=dword:00000000

The value of zero seems to work well, but here's the details on specific values for AllowLSP:
http://www.mobilepractices.com/2007/10/internet-pass-through-connectivity.html